# Apache - How to Redirect /~username to different URL

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

I want to redirect ipaddress/~username/filename to http://newurl.domain.com/filename using Apache Rewrite. Can anyone point out how to do this and specifically to be able to do it for only one user at a time? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you make sure that `mod_userdir` and `mod_rewrite` are enabled, as well as then you can achieve that by creating or editing `~username/public_html/.htaccess` with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newurl.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I believe that you can also achieve the same result without .htaccess, by pasting this configuration snippet inside a `<Directory /home/username/public_html> ... </Directory>` block, but adding the `RewriteBase /~username/` directive as well.